# Magento 2 - How to add product image in order confirmation email ( without object manager )?

Tags: magento2, email-templates, order-email

> Below code is working fine for me...

**Step 1 : Before override** Order confirmation email templates are genereted in below path root_folder/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/defualt.phtml

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */

    // @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

    /** @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\DefaultItems */

    /** @var $_item \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
    $_item = $block->getItem();
    $_order = $_item->getOrder();
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="item-info<?php if ($block->getItemOptions()): ?> has-extra<?php endif; ?>">
            <p class="product-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>
            <p class="sku"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('SKU') ?>: <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSku($_item)) ?></p>
            <?php if ($block->getItemOptions()): ?>
                <dl class="item-options">
                <?php foreach ($block->getItemOptions() as $option): ?>
                    <dt><strong><em><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $option['label'] ?></em></strong></dt>
                    <dd>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  nl2br($option['value']) ?>
                    </dd>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </dl>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $addInfoBlock = $block->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
            <?php if ($addInfoBlock) :?>
                <?= $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml() ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
        </td>
        <td class="item-qty"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getQtyOrdered() * 1 ?></td>
        <td class="item-price">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $block->getItemPrice($_item) ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php if ($_item->getGiftMessageId() && $_giftMessage = $this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->getGiftMessage($_item->getGiftMessageId())):
```

**Step 2 : After override,** Override slaes modules under your theme folder like app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[template]/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/defualt.phtml

```
    /** @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\DefaultItems */

    /** @var $_item \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
    $_item = $block->getItem();
    $_order = $_item->getOrder();
    /* add this line */
    $_store = $_order->getStore();
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="item-info<?php if ($block->getItemOptions()): ?> has-extra<?php endif; ?>">
       /* Start code for displaying product image */
          <?php
            // $_imageHelper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
            // $_baseImageUrl = $_store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product';

            $imageUrl = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')
            ->init($_item->getProduct(), 'product_base_image')
            ->constrainOnly(TRUE)
            ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
            ->keepTransparency(TRUE)
            ->keepFrame(FALSE)
            ->resize(150, 150)->getUrl();
            ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>" alt="some" />
         /* end here  */

            <p class="product-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>
            <p class="sku"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('SKU') ?>: <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSku($_item)) ?></p>
            <?php if ($block->getItemOptions()): ?>
                <dl class="item-options">
                <?php foreach ($block->getItemOptions() as $option): ?>
                    <dt><strong><em><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $option['label'] ?></em></strong></dt>
                    <dd>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  nl2br($option['value']) ?>
                    </dd>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </dl>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $addInfoBlock = $block->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
            <?php if ($addInfoBlock) :?>
                <?= $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml() ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
        </td>
        <td class="item-qty"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getQtyOrdered() * 1 ?></td>
        <td class="item-price">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $block->getItemPrice($_item) ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php if ($_item->getGiftMessageId() && $_giftMessage = $this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->getGiftMessage($_item->getGiftMessageId())):
```

Comment: is this file in atachment responsible to send email

Comment: Exactly,While placing order mail will generate with product name and other order description details

Comment: so override this template and add img tag somewhre in template and as src get progut url from my shaird code

Comment: should i shair code?

Comment: Sure,its pleasure to have a code from yours

Answer (score 0):

**1 .By Object Manager**

```
$product_id = 1;//your product id here
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product       = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
$store         = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();
$imageUrl      = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();
```

hope it will help to get image adn just put it in

```
<img src="<?php echo $imageUrl ?>">
```

**2 .By Dependency inj.**

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context  $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
   \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,        
    .........
    ) {

        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
       ......
    }

    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {

          try {
                $_product = $this->productRepository->getById(2);//Product id here
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                return 'product not found';
            }
            $image_url = $this->imageHelper->init($_product, 'product_base_image')->getUrl();
            echo $image_url;

    }
}
```

.... stands for other dependency

if any help nedeed comment.

Comment: Thanks for sharing dude,but inject object manager is not a good practise in magento that's the reason I did it like that

Comment: so its no phtml is not class how can you do it by dependency ingection

Comment: if you want dependency injection way i can improve ans.

Comment: Can you send me dependency injection to add product image while sending order confirmation email

Comment: Instead of using dependency injection we can go for helper class right,it's gonna reduce our line of code.

Comment: ok wait i will edit code

Comment: Even above my code also working fine dude..

Comment: so what shuld i do? should i shair way with DI or not

Comment: Share dude,It'll usefull for others right

Comment: ok Shure Hope it will help to you too

Comment: sure it'll help me too

Comment: check answer i have added DI way

Comment: did my answer worked for you?

Comment: Hereafter only gonna check man

Comment: ok let me know by accepting answer.

Comment: have my ansswer solved your issue??

Answer (score 0):

To add product images in order confirmation email in Magento 2 without using object manager, you can create a custom module and follow these steps:

1. Create a custom module with a registration.php file in the app/code directory of your Magento installation.
2. Create a di.xml file in the module's etc directory and add the following code to it:

   ```
   <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender">
       <plugin name="add_product_image_to_order_email" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\OrderSender" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
   </type>
   ```

This code will create a plugin for the OrderSender class.

3. Create a plugin class named OrderSender.php in the Vendor/Module/Plugin directory and add the following code to it:

   ```
   <?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

    use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template;
    use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity;
    use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender as Sender;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
    use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

    class OrderSender
    {
    /**
     * @var EventManager
     */
    protected $eventManager;

    /**
     * @param EventManager $eventManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        EventManager $eventManager
    ) {
        $this->eventManager = $eventManager;
    }

    public function aroundSend(Sender $subject, \Closure $proceed, $order, $forceSyncMode = false)
    {
        $objectManager = ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $productImageHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
        $productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');

        $result = $proceed($order, $forceSyncMode);

        $templateContainer = $objectManager->create(Template::class, ['templateContainer' => Template::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE]);

        $productImageWidth = 200;
        $productImageHeight = 200;

        foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
            $product = $productRepository->get($item->getSku());
            $imageUrl = $productImageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')->resize($productImageWidth, $productImageHeight)->getUrl();

            $templateVars = $templateContainer->getTemplateVars();
            $templateVars['items'][$item->getId()]['product_image_url'] = $imageUrl;
            $templateContainer->setTemplateVars($templateVars);
        }

        return $result;
    }
     }
   ```

This code will add a product image URL to the email template vars for each item in the order.

4. Create a custom email template in the app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/email directory and add the following code to it:

   ```
    <!--@subject {{var order.increment_id}} - Your Order @-->
    <!--@vars
    {"store url=\"\"":"Store Url",
     "var formattedShippingAddress|raw":"Formatted Shipping Address",
      "var order.getShippingDescription()":"Shipping Description",
      "var payment_html|raw":"Payment Details",
      "var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')":"Billing Address",
      "var order.getEmailCustomerNote()":"Customer Notification",
      "layout handle=\"sales_email_order_items\" order=$order":"Order Items Grid",
       "var order.getShippingMethod()":"Shipping Method",
       "var order.getShippingDescription()":"Shipping Description",
        "var shipping_msg":"Shipping Message",
        "var gift_msg":"Gift Message",
        "var formattedDiscountAmount":"Discount Amount",
        "var formattedGrandTotal":"Order Total",
        "var formattedSubtotal":"Order Subtotal",
        "var formattedTaxAmount":"Tax Amount",
        "var invoice":"Invoice
   ```